# Page Object Factory with Appium

Tags: appium

I am trying to use Page Object Factory for Appium Test and seem to be having issues linking two pages together.

First Page Below

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import Test2.AbstractPageObject;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AndroidFindBy;
import io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;


public class Test1 {

    public static class PageObject {

        private final WebDriver driver;


        @AndroidFindBy(uiAutomator = "new UiSelector().text(\"Sign in\")")
        private WebElement element;

        public PageObject(WebDriver driver)

        {
            this.driver = driver;
            PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS), this);
        }

        public void click(){
            element.click();
        }
    }

    private PageObject po;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        File appDir = new File("src");
        File app = new File(appDir, "app.apk");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android Emulator");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());

        po = new PageObject(new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities));


    }

    @org.junit.Test
    public void test () {
        AbstractPageObject po = new AbstractPageObject (null);   
        po.test();
    }
```

Second Page

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AndroidFindBy;
import io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class Test2 {

     public static abstract class AbstractPageObject extends Test1 {

            protected final WebDriver driver;       
            public AbstractPageObject(WebDriver driver)
            {
                this.driver = driver;
                PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS), this);
            }
        }   


        public static class PageObject extends AbstractPageObject {

            public PageObject(WebDriver driver) {
                super(driver);
            }
            @FindBy(className="android.widget.ImageButton")
            private WebElement c;
            public void click1()
            {
                c.click();
            }

            @FindBy(id = "com.payment.pay:id/btn_sign_in")
            private WebElement d;
            public void click11()
            {
                d.click();
            }
            @FindBy(id="com.payment.pay:id/btn_forgotten_password")
            private WebElement e;
            public void click111()
            {
                e.click();
            }
            @FindBy(className= "android.widget.ImageButton")
            private WebElement f;
            public void click1111()
            {
                f.click();
            }

            @FindBy(id="com.payment.pay:id/btn_show_pass")
            private WebElement g;
            public void click11111()
            {
                g.click();
            }
        }
}
```

The second page looks okay without error. The error occurs in first page and was unable to import the AbstractPageObject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In Java Abstract classes cannot be instantiated**, but they can be subclassed. Your first page is going to give an error for sure. For more details check this [link](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjE0rqIwtjTAhUHOI8KHfNNDgAQFggnMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2Ftutorial%2Fjava%2FIandI%2Fabstract.html&usg=AFQjCNH4m5TSuGU4Jxf144ikQ74Z3a2vhQ)

Comment: Hi Vinod, how do i resolve it. I have looked at the link but do not understand how to go about it. I would appreciate if you explain this further by making some edits in the First Page. Thank you